# Printing in HTML/iOS app: grab the position of a tapped HTML element and pass it to Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, printing, cordova

I'm developing an HTML application that uses Apache Cordova to comunicate with iOS. Client requirement is to use the printer functionality to print specific docs. To do so, I've created a custom Cordova plugin that allows to print HTML pages.

The implementation I've followed is similar to [Cordova Printer Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer). But during the testing I've encountered a problem: show the popup that displays the available printers in a specific position. In particular, I have a HTML button that when tapped displays that popup. According to [UIPrintInteractionController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010141-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3) there are three main tasks that enable the presentation of that functionality.

```
– presentAnimated:completionHandler:
– presentFromBarButtonItem:animated:completionHandler:
– presentFromRect:inView:animated:completionHandler:
```

My first test was to use `presentAnimated:completionHandler:`. But this method allows to display the popup from the center of the window frame. My goal, instead, is to display the popup from the button that has been tapped. Obviously this in iOS can be achieved without difficulties but here I have an HTML element within a web view and Cordova is the glue between my HTML app and the operative system. So, how can I achieve this?

*Note* Within my project I'm using jQuery and jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Interesting question! Does your button reside inside a table view or is it in the header/footer? i.e. is your button sliding?

Comment: @twil Thanks for your comment. The button is a HTML button inserted within a `UIWebView`. So, I don't have any native element to listen for.

Comment: That goes without saying (button inside `UIWebView`). But does it flow around UI or stay still? the point is you probably could place transparent layer with transparent `UIButton` above HTML counterpart. But move that layer under webview. On clicking HTML button you could bring that layer in front and fake-click transparent button to show printer dialog. How does that sound?

Comment: @twil Sorry for the delay. Could you explain better your advice? I cannot understand. Here I'm working with HTML elements, not native ones. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Well, I haven't tried (or it would be an answer) but `UIWebView` is still `UIView`. You can add other iOS UI components to it and place then above HTML page layer or below. Understant?

Comment: @LorenzoB. Were you able to do this? I am also wondering how to do this.